# how to convert xml to json or javabean?

Tags: java, android, json, xml

Can I convert the following XML into JSON or javabean?

```
<the21stDict>
    <list>
        <listTitle>speak [spi:k]</listTitle>
        <item>
            <itemTitle>vi.</itemTitle>
            <explain>说话，讲话：
                <en>I'm a foreigner. Please speak slowly.</en>
                <cn>我是个外国人，请说得慢一点儿。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>发言，表述意见(或观点等)演讲：
                <en>to speak at the meeting</en>
                <cn>在会议上发言</cn>
                <en>He spoke at the UN for an hour.</en>
                <cn>他在联合国大会上演讲了一个小时。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>(书面)表达，作书面陈述；表明：
                <en>He spoke about his love in the letter.</en>
                <cn>他在信中表达了他的爱意。</cn>
                <en>Actions speak louder than words.</en>
                <cn>行动胜过空谈。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>发信号，打信号：
                <en>He spoke to us with his arms.</en>
                <cn>他用手臂向我们发出信号。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>请求，提要求：
                <en>Don't speak before working.</en>
                <cn>没干活之前，别先提要求。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>(乐器、枪炮等)发声，发响声，发出轰鸣声；发出噪音：
                <en>After an hour of silence,our guns spoke.</en>
                <cn>经过一个小时的沉寂之后，我们的大炮发出了轰鸣声。</cn>
                <en>The violin speaks well.</en>
                <cn>小提琴发出优美动听的旋律。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>有吸引力；有感染力</explain>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemTitle>vt.</itemTitle>
            <explain>说，讲:
                <en>His works were well spoken.</en>
                <cn>他的作品受到了好评。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>说出，讲出：
                <en>to speak the truth</en>
                <cn>说出实情</cn>
                <en>She spoke her thinking about the film.</en>
                <cn>她讲了讲她对那部影片的感受。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>(以书面形式)宣告，表达：
                <en>He spoke his views in his report.</en>
                <cn>在他的报道中，他表达了他的观点。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>用(手势、眼神等)表明；预示，显示：
                <en>The plan was spoken to the public.</en>
                <cn>该项规划已向公众公布。</cn>
                <en>Her face spoke a war between them.</en>
                <cn>她的脸色预示着他们之间的一场吵闹。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>[古语] 显示，证明：
                <en>His absence spoke his lack of sincerity.</en>
                <cn>他不肯来证明了他缺乏诚意。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>[古语]描绘，描述</explain>
            <explain>【航海学】(与过往船只)联络(或打招呼)：
                <en>We spoke a ship with the whistle.</en>
                <cn>我们鸣笛与过往船打招呼。</cn>
            </explain>
            <explain>【计算机】(以音箱等)朗读出(数据、信息等)</explain>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemTitle>n.</itemTitle>
            <explain>语言</explain>
            <explain>[900前]</explain>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemTitle>近义词:</itemTitle>
            <synonyms>converse</synonyms>
            <synonyms>discourse</synonyms>
            <synonyms>talk</synonyms>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemTitle>短语:</itemTitle>
            <phrase>frankly speaking 坦率地说</phrase>
            <phrase>not to speak of
                <exp>更不用说，更谈不上</exp>
                <exp>而且还，除…之外(还)</exp>
            </phrase>
            <phrase>properly speaking 严格说起来</phrase>
            <phrase>speak for oneself
                <exp>为自己辩护</exp>
                <exp>发表自我见解</exp>
                <exp>谈自己的事</exp>
            </phrase>
            <phrase>speak for yourself (或 yourselves) [口语]谈谈你(们)自己；别替我(们)做主</phrase>

        </item>
        <item>
            <itemTitle>变形：</itemTitle>
            <shape>vi. spoke 或 spake . spoken 或 spoke . speaking</shape>
        </item>
    </list>
</the21stDict>
```

I use `java-json.jar` to convert it .

But the result is not satisfactory.

```
{
  "the21stDict": {
    "list": {
      "listTitle": "speak[spi:k]",
      "item": [
        {
          "itemTitle": "vi.",
          "explain": [
            {
              "content": "说话，讲话：",
              "en": "I'm a foreigner. Please speak slowly.",
              "cn": "我是个外国人，请说得慢一点儿。"
            },
            {
              "content": "发言，表述意见(或观点等)演讲：",
              "en": [
                "to speak at the meeting",
                "He spoke at the UN for an hour."
              ],
              "cn": [
                "在会议上发言",
                "他在联合国大会上演讲了一个小时。"
              ]
            },
            {
              "content": "(书面)表达，作书面陈述；表明：",
              "en": [
                "He spoke about his love in the letter.",
                "Actions speak louder than words."
              ],
              "cn": [
                "他在信中表达了他的爱意。",
                "行动胜过空谈。"
              ]
            },
            {
              "content": "发信号，打信号：",
              "en": "He spoke to us with his arms.",
              "cn": "他用手臂向我们发出信号。"
            },
            {
              "content": "请求，提要求：",
              "en": "Don'tspeakbeforeworking.",
              "cn": "没干活之前，别先提要求。"
            },
            {
              "content": "(乐器、枪炮等)发声，发响声，发出轰鸣声；发出噪音：",
              "en": [
                "Afteranhourofsilence,ourgunsspoke.",
                "Theviolinspeakswell."
              ],
              "cn": [
                "经过一个小时的沉寂之后，我们的大炮发出了轰鸣声。",
                "小提琴发出优美动听的旋律。"
              ]
            },
            "有吸引力；有感染力"
          ]
        },
        {
          "itemTitle": "vt.",
          "explain": [
            {
              "content": "说，讲:",
              "en": "Hisworkswerewellspoken.",
              "cn": "他的作品受到了好评。"
            },
            {
              "content": "说出，讲出：",
              "en": [
                "tospeakthetruth",
                "Shespokeherthinkingaboutthefilm."
              ],
              "cn": [
                "说出实情",
                "她讲了讲她对那部影片的感受。"
              ]
            },
            {
              "content": "(以书面形式)宣告，表达：",
              "en": "Hespokehisviewsinhisreport.",
              "cn": "在他的报道中，他表达了他的观点。"
            },
            {
              "content": "用(手势、眼神等)表明；预示，显示：",
              "en": [
                "Theplanwasspokentothepublic.",
                "Herfacespokeawarbetweenthem."
              ],
              "cn": [
                "该项规划已向公众公布。",
                "她的脸色预示着他们之间的一场吵闹。"
              ]
            },
            {
              "content": "[古语]显示，证明：",
              "en": "Hisabsencespokehislackofsincerity.",
              "cn": "他不肯来证明了他缺乏诚意。"
            },
            "[古语]描绘，描述",
            {
              "content": "【航海学】(与过往船只)联络(或打招呼)：",
              "en": "Wespokeashipwiththewhistle.",
              "cn": "我们鸣笛与过往船打招呼。"
            },
            "【计算机】(以音箱等)朗读出(数据、信息等)"
          ]
        },
        {
          "itemTitle": "n.",
          "explain": [
            "语言",
            "[900前]"
          ]
        },
        {
          "itemTitle": "近义词:",
          "synonyms": [
            "converse",
            "discourse",
            "talk"
          ]
        },
        {
          "itemTitle": "短语:",
          "phrase": [
            "franklyspeaking坦率地说",
            {
              "content": "nottospeakof",
              "exp": [
                "更不用说，更谈不上",
                "而且还，除…之外(还)"
              ]
            },
            "properlyspeaking严格说起来",
            {
              "content": "speakforoneself",
              "exp": [
                "为自己辩护",
                "发表自我见解",
                "谈自己的事"
              ]
            },
            "speakforyourself(或yourselves)[口语]谈谈你(们)自己；别替我(们)做主"
          ]
        },
        {
          "itemTitle": "变形：",
          "shape": "vi.spoke或spake.spoken或spoke.speaking"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There are many mistakes

1. If `en` has only one term, it will not generate an array for `en`.So it will fail when I use Gson to convert it to javabean.like:

`<en>I'm a foreigner. Please speak slowly.</en>` convert to `"en": "I'm a foreigner. Please speak slowly."`,
But

```
<en>to speak at the meeting</en>
<cn>在会议上发言</cn>
<en>He spoke at the UN for an hour.</en>
<cn>他在联合国大会上演讲了一个小时。</cn>
```

convert to

```
"en": [
    "to speak at the meeting",
    "He spoke at the UN for an hour."
    ],

"cn": [
    "在会议上发言",
    "他在联合国大会上演讲了一个小时。"
    ]
```

---

2. If explain doesn't have `en` and `cn`, it won't generate the `content` field, which brings me a lot of trouble.

like:

```
<explain>有吸引力；有感染力</explain>
```

convert to

```
"有吸引力；有感染力"
```

---

3. The space of the word in `en` was swallowed:

```
The plan was spoken to the public
```

, It became

```
Theplanwasspokentothepublic
```

So I wonder if there is a good way to achieve it?

Comment: underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xmlstring).

Answer (score 0):

The results of automatic conversion from XML to JSON (or vice versa) are very rarely satisfactory, because doing the job well requires understanding of the semantics of your data. There are many tools you can try out, but they will all have some deficiencies. Consider doing a manual conversion, for example using XSLT 3.0.